# common lisp calling read-line after format produces an additional newline in Clozure CL implementation

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm reading the book Practical Common Lisp and there is a piece of code, and I'm using the Clozure CL implementation:

```
(defun prompt-read (prompt)
 (format *query-io* "~a:" prompt)
 (force-output *query-io*)
 (read-line *query-io*))
```

After I successfully defined the function, I called it by

```
(prompt-read "Hello")
```

And then input "hello" and pressed the enter key, the output is like:

```
CL-USER> (prompt-read "Hello")
Hello:hello

"hello"
NIL
```

an additional blank line is added, I tried the code below and there is no additional newline:

```
(defun test-read ()
 (read-line *query-io*))
```

And then executed it, the result is like:

```
CL-USER> (test-read)
hello
"hello"
NIL
```

This time no additional blank line is produced, actually I find that every time read-line follows a format function, a blank line is produced. I tried the code in Clisp implementation and neither case produces a blank line, I just want to know why the blank line appears, and another question is does read-line return two values? Because I see a NIL following the string I input every time, what does this NIL mean?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm). The second value is whether the input was terminated by EOF rather than a newline.

Comment: I suspect the blank line is being added by the read-eval-print loop, not by `read-line`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your answer, the blank line do seem to be added by the read-eval-print loop, and is dependent on the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The blank line might come from FRESH-LINE

I don't get the output that you describe when I try similar code in SBCL (see appendix).  You didn't mention what implementaiton you're using, but I expect that the REPL is outputting a fresh line, either directly with the **fresh-line** function, or using the tilde-ampersand format directive.  Note what the documentation says about **fresh-line** (emphasis added):

> [**fresh-line**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_terpri.htm) is similar to terpri but outputs a newline only if the
>   output-stream is not already at the start of a line. *If for some
>   reason this cannot be determined, then a newline is output anyway.*
>   fresh-line returns true if it outputs a newline; otherwise it returns
>   false.

It wouldn't surprise me at all if the the prompt that you displayed with **(format *query-io* …)** puts the system in a state where "this cannot be determined," and as a result you get the "extra" newline that you're seeing.  If you change your format directive to something like **"~a:~%"**, do you get the same behavior?

### The NIL

> *and another question is does read-line return two values? Because I
>   see a NIL following the string I input every time, what does this NIL
>   mean?*

As [Barmar pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656148/common-lisp-calling-read-line-after-format-produces-an-additional-newline-in-clo/25656311#comment40091286_25656148), the documentation clearly states that **read-line** returns two values, the second of which indicates whether the input was terminated by a newline or an end-of-file.

> [**read-line**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm) &optional input-stream eof-error-p eof-value recursive-p
>   ⇒ line, missing-newline-p
>
> … The secondary value, missing-newline-p, is a generalized boolean that is false if the line was terminated by a newline, or true if the line was terminated by the end of file for input-stream (or if the line is the eof-value).

### Appendix: SBCL Transcript

```
* (defun prompt-read (x)
    (format *query-io* "~a:" x)
    (force-output *query-io*)
    (read-line *query-io*))

PROMPT-READ
* (prompt-read "Hello")
Hello:hello

"hello"
NIL
* (defun test-read ()
    (read-line *query-io*))

TEST-READ
* (test-read)
hello

"hello"
NIL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use a Clozure CL implementation, and your info about fresh-line is quite useful, I changed my format directive to "~a:~%" then the blank line disappeared, what confused me is that, in Clozure CL implementation, the blank line only appears in prompt-read, not in test-read, in Clisp implementation, neither has a blank line. By the way, what could be the reason that (format *query-io*...) puts the machine in a state where "this cannot be determined"? I really find the iostream confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

That's an interaction of Clozure CL with the SLIME read-eval-print-loop (REPL). The native Clozure CL REPL doesn't do that.

```
; SLIME 2014-05-16
CL-USER> (defun prompt-read (prompt)
           (format *query-io* "~a:" prompt)
           (force-output *query-io*)
           (read-line *query-io*))
PROMPT-READ
CL-USER> (prompt-read "Hello")
Hello:hello

"hello"
NIL
```

If you call it multiple times, then you see that your code does not add a newline, but the REPL prints a line when some output was done, between the output and the values returned.

```
CL-USER> (progn (prompt-read "Hello")
                (prompt-read "Hello")
                (prompt-read "Hello"))
Hello:hello
Hello:hello
Hello:hello

"hello"
NIL
```

Each Lisp implementation has some special code for the SLIME backend. Maybe there is a difference.

Comment: thanks for you answer! Yes, I think it's going to do with the REPL.